lvchange -ay can't activate an LV: device-mapper: reload ioctl on failed: Input/output error
Running on Ubuntu 22.04.4 with kernel 5.15.0-48-generic (yes, there are updates, that is a different issue.)

The only VG named datavg is active and online.
All of the PV are active and online.
All 11 of the other LV are active and online.

movies3 LV causes the error.
Here is a snip from lvchange -vvv output:
  Found raid target v1.15.1.
  Adding target to (253:53): 0 8589950976 raid raid5_ls 3 128 region_size 4096 4 253:45 253:46 253:47 253:48 253:49 253:50 253:51 253:52
  dm table   (253:53) [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
  dm reload   (253:53) [ noopencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:53) failed: Input/output error

There must be a way to force a retry, or move a bad block or something.
What can I do in this case?
It may be this issue: https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/issues/120
How can I activate the logical volume?
Complete lvchange -vvv output is too large to paste here, so I pasted here: https://gist.github.com/jrwren/e5fd91fe937923584d916b710dfc0f56

Your kernel is 5.x . Any particular reason you have not upgraded to 6.x ?

@robgrune AIUI 5.15 is the default for Ubuntu jammy. https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle
